# How can I create a list with a step size different from 1?

Tags: lists, enumerate

I have to type a lot of questions, but only every 4th (4,8,12,...), so I was wondering if I can get Latex to number the items automatically. 
I know I can change each item numbering manually, but I'd like the counter to increase by 4s automatically.

I have no idea where to start, a google search just showed the properties I was already familiar with (arabic, add a label, alph), but nothing referring to a step size. It might be called something different, so I don't know which parameter to set (if any).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a new command that does the trick with everything you know about counters ;)

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\myitem}{\addtocounter{enumi}{3}\item}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \myitem One
  \myitem Two
  \myitem \dots
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

You could create a new command with a step size as argument as well:

```
\newcommand{\myitem}[1]{\addtocounter{enumi}{\numexpr#1-1\relax}\item}
```

Or "set a step size" in the beginning:

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\olditem\item
\newcommand{\myitem}[1]{\addtocounter{enumi}{\numexpr#1-1\relax}\olditem}
\newcommand{\setenumstep}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\item}{\myitem#1}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \myitem4 One
  \myitem4 Two
  \myitem4 \dots
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
  \setenumstep{4}
  \item One
  \item Two
  \item \dots
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

These enumerations both result in the same as the first one posted.

Probably you know it already, but might be helpful anyway: If you want to tweak single items, you can do it manually with

```
\item[4.] One
\item[8.] Two
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're not concerned about `\label`ing the `\item`s, you can use the following setup:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem,etoolbox,xfp}

\newlist{fourenumerate}{enumerate}{4}
\setlist[fourenumerate]{label = {\mulfour{\value*}.}}

\newrobustcmd{\mulfour}[1]{\inteval{#1 * 4}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item One
  \item Two
  \item \ldots
\end{enumerate}

\begin{fourenumerate}
  \item One
  \item Two
  \item \ldots
\end{fourenumerate}

\end{document}
```